# How to Sum the SQL smalldatetime values in SQL server report Expression

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB.net & SQL server 2008 and I am trying to get the Total Worked hours (Sum) in SQL report which is datatype is smalldatetime and I tried the below codes which already posted in a previously asked question. The my problem is the first method is giving me an #error and the second method is giving me wrong calculation. If anyone can help me with this I am really grateful.

1st Method which gave me an #error as below

```
=TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(Fields!TheTime.Value))
```

2nd method Which gave me wrong calculation as below

```
=Date.FromOADate(Sum(Fields!TheTime.Value.ToOADate())).ToString("hh:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Please add the value of the "wrong calculation" and your expected value. Additionally it would help to see some sample data of your table containing the Total Worked Hours.

Comment: There are 18 Line of data input with 8:00 hrs each. my expected amount is 144:00 but it shows 00:00.

Comment: `=Format(CDate(Sum(Fields!TheTime.Value)), "hh:mm")` does this work?

Comment: Its giving you 00:00 because it adding time - In essence if you start at midnight and add 18 lots of 8h you end up 144 hours in the future (exactly 6 days) and the time at the end will be midnight again. In the past I have used a hidden column where I had converted each time into an integer of minutes. The total column the sum(ed) the mins and the converted this into hours and remaining mins.

Comment: Dear Mych8,Thanks For the tip can you please post some sample expression. it will be great help if you can. Sorry If I troubled you...

Comment: Dear Alex B, That didn't work, anyway thank you very much for trying to help me.

Comment: I would think you would have to treat your time data for hours as Single (or Double) to do the math. Are you sure your hours worked are stored as SmallDateTime on the server? Typically they would be stored as numbers (Decimal(5,2)?). You may be able to do the conversion with the query.

Comment: Dear rheitzman, Yes The Data stored as smalldatetime.